# embedded linux C code to perform cp from USB drive to directory on host keeping directory structure in tact

Tags: c, linux, usb, embedded-linux, cp

I have an embedded linux kit AM335x (running angstrom 3.2.0, pc is running ubuntu 12.0.4) where I can plug in a USB Flash Drive.

The USB Flash Drive has multiple folders, sub-folders and files.

I would like to create some C code to copy these folders and files from the mass storage device to the file system on my kit.

I would want to do this somewhat in multiple copies so I could check to see if there was still room in the file system I am copying to.

I had found the following (see code below) and was trying to use it. Unfortunately it does not keep keep the directory structure on the USB drive intact when copying over.

For example if I tried the following: Copy(/media/sda1/foo/foo.txt, "/home/Usb_Files");

I see foo.txt at /home/Usb_Files/foo.txt instead of /home/Usb_Files/foo/foo.txt

Also if I try Copy(/media/sda1/foo/foo.txt, "/home/Usb_Files/foo");

It says the cp cannot stat no such file or directory

Any idea on how to do this?

I am really stuck.

```
int Copy(char *source, char *dest)
{
    int childExitStatus;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    if (!source || !dest) {
    /* handle as you wish */
    }

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) { /* child */
    execl("/bin/cp", "/bin/cp", "-R", source, dest, (char *)0);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
    /* error - couldn't start process - you decide how to handle */
    }
    else {
    /* parent - wait for child - this has all error handling, you
     * could just call wait() as long as you are only expecting to
     * have one child process at a time.
     */
    pid_t ws = waitpid( pid, &childExitStatus, WNOHANG);
    if (ws == -1)
    { /* error - handle as you wish */
    }
if( WIFEXITED(childExitStatus)) /* exit code in childExitStatus */
{
status = WEXITSTATUS(childExitStatus); /* zero is normal exit */
/* handle non-zero as you wish */
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(childExitStatus)) /* killed */
{
}
else if (WIFSTOPPED(childExitStatus)) /* stopped */
{
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because your embedded linux filesystem don't have foo directory,so you need to create foo directory before copying.

You need to add logic to check whether directory is present or not before any operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at `/media/sda1/foo/foo.txt` you implicitly know that you would divide it into the two parts `/media/sd1a` and `/foo/foo.txt` -- the question is how do you implement this knowledge into your program?  For example, is the dividing point always the second slash or is it some other rule?
Once you have this information, you will want do divide it again before the last slash (e.g. giving `/foo` in this case) -- this will give you the directory structure you need to create in the destination.  Take a look at `mkdir -p` to help with this (e.g. `mkdir -p /home/Usb_Files/foo`).